# How does Fat-Free Framework get post api request?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I want to create an API POST handler on Fat-Free Framework.

When I send any test POST request inside the application, nothing happens, can't find the reason for the error.

**Sending a request**

```
$dataContainers = [
            'type' => 1, 
            'units' => 1, 
            'container' => 1,
        ];
    
$query = http_build_query($data);
    
$options = ['http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => ['Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'],
            'content' => $query,
            ],
            ];
    
$context = stream_context_create($options);
    
$response = @file_get_contents('/api/packer/containers', false, $context);
```

**Routing .ini**

```
POST /api/packer/containers = App\Controller\Packer\PackerApiController->setContainers
```

**Controller**

```
class PackerApiController
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct($f3, $params)
    {
     // Trying to test get and return any data
     $params; // empty
     $post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); // empty
     $post = json_decode($f3->get('BODY'), true); // empty

     header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
     header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
     header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

     return json_encode($post);
}
}
```

Comment: Remove the `@` from `@file_get_contents` in case that is suppressing an error

Comment: Also, in your sending code, you wrote `$response =`...etc, but then you haven't shown us any code to actuall display that response. e.g. `var_dump($response);`. Then you can actually see what the request returned.

Comment: I doubt that `file_get_contents` will make an HTTP request, simply based on that you passed in an HTTP stream context ...? You should give it an actual HTTP/HTTPS URL as argument, and not what will probably get interpreted as a local file system path.

Comment: @CBroe Please advise how to write a path so that it works locally when testing and on the server?

Comment: I don't know what your local URLs look like ... something like `http://mytestsystem.local/api/packer/containers` ...

Comment: Make the base of the URL a configuration variable so you can load it in at runtime, and set a different value in each environment

Answer (score 1):

You defined the route to point to a `setContainers` method of the `PackerApiController`. But then you try to handle the request in the constructor of this class. Create the method and move the code to it.